# E/launcher - Error: TypeError: Cucumber.Cli is not a function

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumber, bdd

While implementing BDD I developed a test using protractor, cucumber and protractor-cucumber framework.

I don't know what to do with the `index.js` file.

While running the tests I'm getting the error:

```
"E/launcher - Error: TypeError: Cucumber.Cli is not a function"
```

I am using:

- cucumber@2.0.0-rc2
- protractor@4.0.13
- protractor-cucumber-framework@0.6.0

Here is the detailed error message:

```
[11:22:34] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
[11:22:34] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[11:22:37] E/launcher - Error: TypeError: Cucumber.Cli is not a function
    at C:\Users\jxm\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ProtractorCucumber_FromScratch\ProtractorCucumber_FromScratch\node_modules\protractor-cucumber-framework\index.js:31:16
    at Function.promise (C:\Users\jxm\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ProtractorCucumber_FromScratch\ProtractorCucumber_FromScratch\node_modules\q\q.js:682:9)
    at C:\Users\jxm\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ProtractorCucumber_FromScratch\ProtractorCucumber_FromScratch\node_modules\protractor-cucumber-framework\index.js:24:14
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\jxm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\jxm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\jxm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\Users\jxm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (C:\Users\jxm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\Users\jxm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
[11:22:37] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem yesterday - for some reason it doesnt work work when installing cucumber@2.0.0-rc2

I believe its because when installing protractor-cucumber-framework its says : UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY cucumber@2.0.0-rc.2

so seems this version of cucumber is incompatible.

I did: npm install --save-dev cucumber@1.3.1

Then it worked. I believe this is a protractor-cucumber-framework problem

Answer (score 1):

**Cucumber@2.0.0** has some breaking changes to the cucumber cli, this is breaking the protractor-cucumber-framework which is written using an older version of cucumber.

An issue has already been logged in the official [protractor-cucumber-framework](https://github.com/mattfritz/protractor-cucumber-framework/issues/64) github repo.

Work Around for now would be to downgrade your cucumber version.